# VScode freezes my laptop in ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, freeze, bug-reporting, visual-studio-code

When I run **vscode** everything works fine.

After a short period of time, the laptop gradually slows down until it freezes completely.

I thought the problem was in the system, but on this site I found someone with the same problem as me and saw the solution, but it didn't work or I didn't understand the solution well.

**Update:**

All programs work well, the problem in vscode.

Ubuntu version **22.04.1LTS**

Hardware :
**4GB** Ram
**1TB** HDD
**AMD E2-9000** (1.8GHZ up to 2.2GHZ dual core)

I ran the htop but when it freezes i can't do anything to open the htop. Is there any way to see the htop logs?

Comment: There’s an insufficient amount of information here, making it impossible to offer you anything of value. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the correct version of Ubuntu that you’re running (1) the hardware specs of your computer (2) whether the slowdown only happens when vscode is *not* running (your question is unclear, as you seem to say your computer is fine so long as that program is active) (3) what other applications are running when the slowdown takes place. With this information, it *may* be possible to identify next steps 

Comment: most noticeable thing is 4GB RAM, can you run `htop` or `top` and use vscode, while monitoring RAM usage? if your RAM is running out maybe add some swap?